# apply a function on the html appended by .ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to vertically align a picture, that is returned from the ajax but when I do that on the pictures (HTML) returned from ajax, it does not apply. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "extra.php",
    data: mystr,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $('.mydiv').empty();
        $(".mydiv").append(html);
        middle_align();     
    }
});
```

here is what i am appending

```
echo '
<div id="box">
<img src="'.$path.$name.'.jpg"  class="loadimg" />
                </div>  ';
```

and here is the middle align function

```
function middle_align(){
     var child = $(".loadimg").height();
     var parent = $("#box").height();
 var margin = (parent - child)/2;
  $(".box").children("img").css('margin-top', margin); 
                    }
```

The function works well everywhere else but not on the data loaded by ajax. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making the ajax synchronous,
`async : false`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
success: function(html) {
$('.mydiv').html('');
$(".mydiv").append(html);
var child = $(".loadimg").height();
var parent = $("#box").height();
margin =(parent - child) / 2 ;
$("#box").find("img").css('margin-top', margin);
}
```